# Node.js Promises returning undefined for some elements, what am I doing wrong or what can I improve?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, domcrawler

Some of my promises are returning "undefined" and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Tried to add a timeout but didn't solve it, I'm still learing and struggling to see my error.

it looks like the issue on scrapeSpecificOperatorStats block, however some returns are fine.

Example:
expect:

```json
  {
    name: 'Kapkan',
    imageUrl: 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/7MofnDHeL1uwsenBVjxplQ/1e5af8fe9cf6f36516c7f6e5d56fcac0/r6-operators-list-kapkan.png',
    linkUrl: 'https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/rainbow-six/siege/game-info/operators/kapkan',
    operatorStats: { specialty: 'ANTI-ENTRY, TRAPPER' }
  }
```

actual:

```json
  {
    name: 'Kapkan',
    imageUrl: 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/7MofnDHeL1uwsenBVjxplQ/1e5af8fe9cf6f36516c7f6e5d56fcac0/r6-operators-list-kapkan.png',
    linkUrl: 'https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/rainbow-six/siege/game-info/operators/kapkan',
    operatorStats: undefined
  }
```

the issue is only on **operatorStats** and only for some of the elements

My code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

// Define the URL of the webpage
const url = "https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/rainbow-six/siege/game-info/operators";

// Define a function to scrape the operator stats from the link URL
const scrapeSpecificOperatorStats = async (link) => {
  try {
    // Make a HTTP request to the webpage
    const response = await axios.get(link);

    // Load the HTML content into Cheerio
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    // Find and Extract the operator specialty
    const specialty = $("span.operator__header__roles").text();

    // Return the results
    return { specialty };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// Define a function to scrape the operator stats
const scrapeOperatorStats = async (url) => {
  try {
    // Make a HTTP request to the webpage
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    // Load the HTML content into Cheerio
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    // Find the element that contains the operator stats
    const statsElement = $(".oplist__card");

    // Create an array of promises for each operator stat element
    const statsPromises = statsElement.map(async (index, element) => {
      // Extract the operator name, specialty, and description
      const name = $(element).find("span").text();

      // Extract the image URL and link URL
      const imageUrl = $(element).find("img").attr("src");
      const linkUrl = "https://www.ubisoft.com" + $(element).attr("href");

      // Get the operator stats
      const operatorStats = await scrapeSpecificOperatorStats(linkUrl);

      // Return the result
      return {
        name,
        imageUrl,
        linkUrl,
        operatorStats,
      };
    });

    // Wait for all promises to resolve and return the results
    return Promise.all(statsPromises);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// Call the function and log the results
scrapeOperatorStats(url)
  .then((results) => console.log(results))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `scrapeSpecificOperatorStats` returns `undefined` when an error occurs, because you have a `try`/`catch` and the `catch` just logs out the error. That means execution falls off the end of the function, which does an implicit return of `undefined`.

To fix it, either allow errors in `scrapeSpecificOperatorStats` to propagate rather than converting them to `undefined` (by removing the `try`/`catch`) and handle them at a higher level (such as in `scrapeOperatorStats`), or handle the fact `scrapeSpecificOperatorStats` returns `undefined` when an error occurs. Your best bet is usually the former; handling errors too early is a common anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the light... it helps, althought I still get error: 

`AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 429', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: ClientRequest, …}
`

I've updated the code to use timeout before getting the next operator stats, but no luck.

`await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
      // Get the operator stats
      const operatorStats = await scrapeSpecificOperatorStats(linkUrl); 
`

Comment: It is working now, changed to :
`const statsPromises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < statsElement.length; i++) {
      const element = statsElement[i];`
now my setTimeout is in effect and I get the proper returns.